# The partial fraction decomposition of $\dfrac{x}{x^3-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I was trying to decompose $\dfrac{x}{x^3-1}$ into Partial Fractions. I tried the following:
$$\dfrac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\dfrac{A}{(x-1)}+\dfrac{B}{(x^2+x+1)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow A(x^2+x+1)+B(x-1)=x$$
Putting $x=1,$
$$A(1+1+1)+B(1-1)=1\Rightarrow A=\dfrac{1}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{3}(x^2+x+1) +B(x-1)=x$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^2+x+1)+3Bx-3B=x$$
$$x^2+(3B+1)x +(1-3B)=x$$
At this point I gave up thinking I must have done something wrong since there is no $x^2$ on the RHS while it is there in the LHS.

I would be truly grateful if somebody would be so kind to help me understand my mistake. Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a partial fraction decomposition, the numerator of a term with a quadratic denominator (or a power of a quadratic in the denominator) should have the form $$Bx+C,$$ and not just a constant. Tracing through your argument, we see we pick up the algebra at the antepenultimate display equation:
$$\frac{1}{3}(x^2 + x + 1) = (B x + C)(x - 1).$$
So, we can see that this correction introduces a new quadratic term $Bx^2$ (with an unknown coefficient), which fixes precisely the problem you've observed with the given method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Sir, in general suppose the largest power of the denominator was $n$. Then what should the numerator be, Sir?

Comment: Sir, suppose the denominator was $a^n+a^{n-1}+...+a^{n-(n-1)}+a^0$. Then corresponding to every term in the denominator, would we have a corresponding term in the numerator with the exponent to which the term in the denominator was raised reduced by 1?

Comment: For example, suppose the denominator is $a^4+a^2+1$. Then would the numerator be $$Ba^3+Ca+D?$$ Or would it be $$Ba^3+Ca^2+Da+E?$$

Comment: @MakeaDifference: First you need to factor completely, then decompose. The only terms you can have are linear terms and their powers, and quadratic terms and their powers - every polynomial can be factored into those. For every factor $(ax+b)^n$ you have $n$ terms $c_1/(ax+b)^1$ up to $c_n/(ax+b)^n$, and for every factor $(ax^2+bx+c)^n$ you have $n$ terms $(c_1+d_1x)/(ax^2+bx+c)^1$ to $(c_n+d_nx)/(ax^2+bx+c)^n$.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld Sir, please could you explain the meaning of "linear terms and their powers, and quadratic terms and their powers"? I'm trying to understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: @MakeaDifference I just saw your comment but I see there's no need to answer it, as Meni already has done so ably.

Comment: @MakeaDifference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition gives a reasonably thorough introduction; Example 3 gives a case like the one you ask about, where the denominator has a repeated quadratic factor.

Comment: @Travis Thanks very much Sir, for helping me!

Comment: @MakeaDifference For example, if the denominator is $x^8-3x^7+2x^6-2x^5+6x^4-4x^3+x^2-3x+2$, you can factor it to $(x-2)(x-1)^3(x^2+x+1)^2$, which has a linear term ($x-2$), a power of a linear term ($(x-1)^3$), and a power of a quadratic term ($(x^2+x+1)^2$).

Comment: @MakeaDifference You're welcome, I'm glad you found my comments helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x}{x^3-1}=\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$

$\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x+1}$

$x=A(x^2+x+1)+(Bx+C)(x-1)$

Let $x=1$

$1=A(1^2+1+1)$

$1=3A$

$A=\frac{1}{3}$

So, $x=\frac{1}{3}(x^2+x+1)+(Bx+C)(x-1)$

$x=\frac{1}{3}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}+Bx^2-Bx+Cx-C$

$x=(\frac{1}{3}+B)x^2+(\frac{1}{3}-B+C)x+\frac{1}{3}-C$

Compare the coefficient,

$0x^2=(\frac{1}{3}+B)x^2$

$\frac{1}{3}+B=0$, $B=-\frac{1}{3}$

$x=(\frac{1}{3}-B+C)x$

$\frac{1}{3}-B+C=1$

$\frac{1}{3}-(-\frac{1}{3})+C=1$

$C=\frac{1}{3}$

Therefore,

$$\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{1}{3(x-1)}+\frac{-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}}
{x^2+x+1}$$

Simplify it and get $\frac{1}{3(x-1)}+\frac{1-x}{3(x^2+x+1)}$